# Where can I find 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Tags: downloads, 32-bit

I need to find the 32-bit version, and all I keep finding is the 64-bit. Can anyone provide me with a link?

Comment: You might find it labeled as x86 or i386

Comment: "I need to find the 32-bit version, and all I keep finding is the 32-bit." Should that second 32 be a 64?

Comment: The Ubuntu 32-bit iso files contain the string `i386` in the file name. (The corresponding 64-bit iso files contain the string `amd64` in the file name.)

Comment: Related: [What options do I have to upgrade an unsupported i386 version of Ubuntu to an operating system with newer packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361769/124466)

Answer (score 44):

Update: Ubuntu and derivatives stopped releasing 32bit images.

As http://ubuntu.com now offers only 64bit releases, 32bit images are harder to find.

Here they are:

18.04

- [Xubuntu 18.04.5 direct download](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso)

- [Mate 18.04.5 - direct download](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/18.04.5/release/ubuntu-mate-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso)

Comment: You might include in your answer what @matega says, 32-bit versions are postfixed with `x86` or `i386`

Comment: Good point about i386. Are Ubuntu images postfixed with x86?

Comment: x86_64 == 64 bits. x86 == 32 bits.

Comment: for the latest 32 bit desktop release [16.04] http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: Most supported 32 bit releases can be found on the [alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) page.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for the heads up. Fixed them.

Comment: I tried to download from this link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso, but always failed. Is someone here have a link that I can really use to download the latest version of Ubuntu 32-bit Intel processor?

Comment: What is Ubuntu-Mate? Is it mature enough to be used for normal use?

Comment: @AirCraftLover The latest version is unavailable as a 32bit ISO. I also do not think it would have been practical to use on old 32bit only hardware. It won't work well. The above linked ISOs are the best *buntus for 32bit machines.

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/xubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: For 16.04: https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ Select 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image.

Answer (score 7):

The most popular **currently supported** Ubuntu releases can always be found [here.](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) If the flavor you are looking for isn't there, try [this page.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/) The 32 bit version files end in `-i386.iso` while the 64 bit versions end in `-amd64.iso` but also run on Intel 64-bit CPU's.

Regardless of which flavor iso you decide to install, it's always prudent to insure that you have a valid download by [checking the hash.](https://askubuntu.com/a/503788/225694)

This answer should not only work now, but into the future as well. If you've landed here because you can't find the 32-bit live installer you can still use the network installer found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) as mentioned in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092435/225694)

Answer (score 1):

### Comments and links about LTS systems

The answer by @ElderGeek is independent of the current versions and therefore very good.

I want to add some details to that answer in order **to find the version with the longest remaining support time (until 'end of life')**, which is often the first point release of an LTS release. Right now, when this is written, it is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, and I cannot find its iso files via the links in the answer by @ElderGeek.

The support intervals are described with details and diagrams in this link,

[www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)

The kernel series of the second, third and fourth point releases are different from the kernel series of the first point release, and are not supported for a long time. The hardware enablement stack must/will be upgraded according to these links,

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack)

in order to keep everything up to date (including security updates of the kernel).

Problems are reported, I think particularly for **old hardware**, where you would use **32-bit** Ubuntu or a light-weight 'Ubuntu community flavour', Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu. Some of these problems can be found, if you type **HWE** into the 'Search Q&A' window near the top right corner of the web browser's window with AskUbuntu (and press Enter).

The kernel series of the fifth point release is that of the next LTS relesase and has long time support.

### Strategy for a stable and reliable system

I suggest a strategy using LTS releases at this link,

[Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release/956148#956148)

### Get the iso files

Start looking for the iso files of the version with the longest remaining support via these links,

- **[releases.ubuntu.com/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)** or for the community flavours **[cdimage.ubuntu.com/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/)**

If the iso files of the version with the longest remaining support are not found via those links, you can find them via the following general link,

- **[old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com)**

and right now, when this is written, you want to find **Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS** via the following link,

- **[old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/)**

Comment: Starting with the 16.04, the hwe kernel changed to be rolling, so users would be automatically updated, without these users having to do some rigmarole. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16410/158442. This answer is misleading.

Comment: @muru,  I have installed systems installed via an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS iso file. They are fully updated & full-upgraded. They stay with the xenial kernel, the 4.4 series (now at 4.4.0-93). `lsb_release -a` reports 16.04.3 LTS, and that may reflect the rest of the software, but not the kernel, because Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS is delivered with the 4.10 kernel series (of 17.04). Please check in an own system, if you don't believe what I am writing ;-)

Comment: @muru, Maybe you mean that the users should use some kind of automatic upgrade of the HWE stack. I have seen too many reports about failure of that process to recommend it, particularly for people who want a stable Ubuntu system.

Comment: @muru, **GA - the stable alternative**: Security updates and bug fixes provided as SRU’s to the GA kernel still remain under the GA umbrella for the full 5yrs of support; **HWE alternatives:** We will roll to the newest HWE Stack offering around the time of the point release introducing that HWE Stack: This is what has causes failures (I think with hardware compatibility).

Comment: you keep saying too many reports, but you don't link to any. Also, the very page you link to says that 16.04.2 installs the hwe kernel by default. I don't have to check anything, I switched my 16.04 system to the hwe kernel when I upgraded.

Comment: @muru, I have read such reports at the Ubuntu Forums (and I think here too). I will try to find links and add them here. I think the problems are bigger with aging hardware, where compatibility sometimes is dropped from one kernel series with its hardware drivers to the next kernel series with new (updated) kernel drivers. I think this is a general problem with rolling releases. -- Do you want me to remove this answer, if I cannot find any good links?

Comment: @muru, Older problems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manual-tests/+bug/1602066/comments/5 ; https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2330466&p=13527594#post13527594 ; Newer problems: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bugs?orderby=-importance&memo=75&start=75 (look for 4.10 (kernel version) ; https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1702714 ; https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101998

Comment: and do you have comparative data for older releases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65682/discussion-between-sudodus-and-muru).

Comment: @muru, I am continuing in chat.

Comment: @sudodus You'll note that point releases currently aren't reported separately at the first link referenced in your answer. This makes sense since as you know you can install a .1 release (for example)  and upgrade it to the current point release easily. Cheers!

Comment: @ElderGeek, Yes, this has changed - things are easier to manage now. The first diagram of [www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) is what you describe. If you scroll further down, there is a more detailed diagram with all the point releases.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, I see that but if you look closely it seems it's more a factor of kernel version than point release that determines the support "These kernels are all supported for the full life of their underlying LTS release."

Comment: @ElderGeek, It seems we are interpreting that sentence in different ways. I read: "LTS kernel series (for example 4.15 is an LTS release and is supported for the full life of its underlying LTS release, but not 4.18). The system will be upgraded automatically from the second point release with the 4.18 kernel series via the next point releases and their kernels to point release 5 with the kernel series of the next LTS release." But I may be wrong.

Comment: @sudodus :-) Oh the never-ending search for clarity. I too may be mistaken.