# Download link for ubuntu 32-bit

Tags: 32-bit

ubuntu download link for 32-bit
I do not find a link to download the latest version of ubuntu 32-bit, please help me! I want to install ubuntu on my PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find 32-bit version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768415/where-can-i-find-32-bit-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

All downloads (torrents):

- [Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop 32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.10/ubuntu-16.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.157492089.278333181.1478992548)
- [Ubuntu 16.10 Server 32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.10/ubuntu-16.10-server-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.187845739.278333181.1478992548)
- [Ubuntu 16.04.1 Desktop 32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.187845739.278333181.1478992548)
- [Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server 32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.187845739.278333181.1478992548)
- [Ubuntu MATE 18.04 Desktop 32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-mate-18.04-desktop-i386.iso)

Next time please refer to their [download page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads):

Comment: Well, given that OP can't really navigate a download page then you should probably reference him to the links of the .iso's.

Comment: hello brother, but the size of the file is only 57.4 KB?

Comment: It should be a `.torrent` file. You use a BitTorrent client such as µTorrent to download Ubuntu using that file.