# Trouble Installing Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 18.04 with Unibootin. When I boot into the installation, I got a message that says

```
Unable to boot. Please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I downloaded the right architecture

Comment: The only time I get that message is if I load a amd64 image and try and boot on an i686 (or less) based computer.   The other option was you didn't check your downloaded ISO was perfect (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or check write to install media was flawless (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no 32 bit ISO for the new Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028872/why-is-there-no-32-bit-iso-for-the-new-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot CD won't boot with a "x86-64 CPU,but only detected an i686 CPU" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42041/boot-cd-wont-boot-with-a-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-error)

Answer (score 3):

1. Downloading the Ubuntu ISO is [from this weblink](https://ubuntu.com/download); Ubuntu 'flavours' with alternate desktop environments, [are downloaded from here](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).

   > However, if you have a 32-bit CPU you must use
   >
   > - [Kubuntu 32-bit 18.04.3](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/),
   > - [Lubuntu 32-bit 18.04.3](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/),
   > - [Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.3](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads),
   > - [Ubuntu MATE 32-bit 18.04.3](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/),
   > - [Ubuntu 32-bit 16.04.06](http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-iso/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso),   or
   > - [Xubuntu 32-bit 18.04.3](https://xubuntu.org/download#lts).
   >
   > instead of any of the later releases. The 32-bit Network Installer for Ubuntu 19.10 [has been withdrawn](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/19.10/), but the 32-bit [Network Installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot) for Ubuntu 18.04 [is still available](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/).
2. Once the ISO file downloaded, verify it arrived with no corruption [following these steps](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).
3. Installation, as per Canonical, Ubuntu's publishers, is typically done on [another Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) with [Startup Disk Creator](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) or on a [Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) using the Open Source Windows app [Rufus](https://rufus.ie), not with *Unibootin* (sic) or [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).
4. Once you make a LiveUSB, install it [following these steps](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).