# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 - Samsung p510 Laptop

Tags: 18.04, samsung

I have an old Samsung Laptop and I am just curious as to whether there are any issues when installing Ubuntu to replace Windows 7.

Comment: Do you wamt to ask,how to install it?

Comment: None with version > 11.10 (last issue found http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1872149 ) as per a search http://google.com/search?q=Samsung+p510+Ubuntu+-Lenovo . But if you add Ubuntu to the internal drive of the p510 or install it to a large USB drive, & keep Win7 for a while, you can test it extensively for any issues; chose Install Alongside Windows. Update to the latest Samsung BIOS for Windows first http://samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/np510r5e.and upgrade it to 4GB RAM,  else it doesn't meet minimal specs for Ubuntu help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only 2GB RAM, download a 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

LiveUSB creation is typically done following these instructions on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 https://askubuntu.com/a/1188561/197910

Although some flavours use a different installer, the steps are very similar.