# Latest version of Ubuntu for i386 architecture (32 bit)

Tags: iso, 32-bit

I was looking for the latest version of Ubuntu for i386 (32 bit)

- [ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/17.04/)
- [ubuntu-17.10.1-server-i386.iso](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/17.10/)

It is it right ?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 or the 2017-October release is EOL (*end-of-life*). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/19/ubuntu-17-10-artful-aardvark-end-of-life-reached-on-july-19-2018/   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ubuntu produced i386 ISOs into the disco (19.04) cycle which was well past *artful* or 17.10; it's just that fewer ISO options were provided; eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ISOs were produced (including *flavors*), just no desktop ISO, but you could use another ISO & add the desktop as Ubuntu Desktop was fully supported in 18.04; just no i386 Desktop ISO produced. Ubuntu Desktop didn't make much sense with 18.04 as few i386 machines met the specs; *flavors* made more sense & they were produced (two flavors also produced 18.10 released products, and continued into 19.04).  i386 was only disabled in eoan

Comment: Because 18.10 & 19.04 are EOL; the 18.04 LTS is the last i386 release still with some support  (excluding ESM which is off-topic here)

Comment: You find a lot of detailed support for old computers at [this Ubuntu Forums link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640).

Comment: i386 (32-bit) install .iso were dropped after 19.04 for two main reasons: 1) The Gnome experience on 32-bit was rather poor, and 2) A shortage of 32-bit volunteers willing to do the testing and work on #1. Many 32-bit libraries remain in the Ubuntu repositories to support common 32-bit applications (like Steam). Debian still has a 32-bit desktop installer. There is no policy prohibiting resumption of a full Ubuntu 32-bit desktop; it merely requires enough volunteers to do the work required.

Comment: I believe @user535733 meant 17.04 in the prior comment (not 19.04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no 32 bit ISO for the new Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028872/why-is-there-no-32-bit-iso-for-the-new-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thanks guiverc, N0rbert, I used [lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only supported i386 release is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/   is an example of an 18.04 i386 Ubuntu ISO. It allows you to install Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS, though you need to ensure your machine meets the [Minimum System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Ubuntu produced i386 ISOs into the disco (19.04) cycle which was well past *artful* or 17.10; it's just that fewer ISO options were provided; eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ISOs were produced (including *flavors*), just no desktop ISO, but you could use another ISO & add the desktop as Ubuntu Desktop was fully supported in 18.04; just no i386 Desktop ISO produced.

Ubuntu Desktop didn't make much sense with 18.04 as few `i386` machines met the minimum system requirements; *flavors* made more sense & they were produced for 18.04; with two flavors (Lubuntu & Xubuntu) also producing & released 18.10, and continued into the 19.04 development cycle. If a 19.04 *alpha* ISO was installed; it received updates the life of 19.04.

i386 was only finally disabled in *beta* stage of eoan or 19.10.

Opinion: *I QA-tested 18.04 using pentium M, pentium D, pentium 4 & early atom machines; and none were capable of really running a GNOME desktop; even the pentium D which was dual core struggled & whilst it may have "*run*", it was more of a very slow "*walk*" that wasn't fun to use - *flavors* made much more sense in my opinion; as all i386 CPUs ran the lighter *flavors* much better*

Comment: Technically; all Ubuntu 18.04 LTS *flavors* have reached & passed their EOL; as *flavors* came with 3 years of support; it was only Ubuntu Desktop, Server, Cloud & like products that had the 3 years extended to 5 years. If for example you installed Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (now EOL), the base system still receives upgraded packages, and I think of now as a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system with LXDE; not as Lubuntu anymore (*but maybe that's just me - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS receives support & is on-topic here until 2023-April*)

Comment: Not only Ubuntu Desktop but also Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS is still supported. An old computer can still be useful as a file server (much more so that a desktop system, that is lagging because the hardware cannot cope with the desktop environment).

Comment: Yeah I didn't mention server in the answer (I did in the subsequent comment about *flavors*; *quoting badly what I've pasted many times into the fridge notices*..)   Most i386 hardware was PATA, and the few that had SATA were rather slow & not *fast* servers, at least in my experience.. Yes I've got really old servers still (with SCSI & SAS drives) but they're all *amd64* even up to 20 years ago.