# New 18.04 install old Toshiba A75 ATI Radeon 9000 graphics suspends when booting

Tags: boot, suspend, amd-graphics

Installed from dvd (used successfully to load on old Gateway). I had to use "nomodeset" to get the dvd to load for trial or install screen to display or the system would go to blackscreen.  I can stop at grub menu and see that "nomodeset" is set in the linux load.  When I continue, I can no longer see the boot echo on screen, just black screen and then goes into suspend state after approximately 15 seconds.  Only loading Kubuntu on clean drive.  I am new to linux with some unix background.  Tried a number of things after much reading and did new install before writing this.

Comment: ...and what happens if you boot without `nomodeset`? Also, Kubuntu is probably a huge overkill for a machine this old. Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768415/where-can-i-find-32-bit-version-of-ubuntu/768419?noredirect=1#comment1851217_768419) for more suitable options.

Comment: The dvd will start loading, I can get an echo on the screen using the down arrow key but it will go into suspend numerous times.  After using power button to get out of suspend, it will continue from the last point but usually goes to a distorted color screen (I think when first graphic screen loads) then goes black screen and unresponsive.  Thanks for response.