# Is there to be a New release '18.10' available for 32-bit?

Tags: 32-bit, do-release-upgrade

I have a 32-bit machine running 18.04, and it keeps saying

> New release '18.10' available.

Nut when I run the release upgrade it says half way through the procedure that 32-bit version is not available yet.

Is there to be a date for 32-bit 18.10 to be available?

Comment: Related: [Where can I find 32-bit version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/768415/301745)

Answer (score 10):

No. There never will be another Ubuntu that is 32-bit.

You will need to switch to an alternative. Some of the official flavors intend to keep 32-bit in their arsenal. But I would assume they will stick to LTS for 32-bit.

3 examples:

- [Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads). 18.04 is 64 and 32. 19.04 is 64 only. No 18.10 download.
- [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download/) 18.04 is 64 and 32. 19.04 is 64 only. No 18.10 download.
- [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/downloads/) has a 32 for 18.10 listed on their main site.

===

More on this:

[Canonical Considering To Drop 32 Bit Support In Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-32-bit-support-drop/)

> Yesterday, developer Dimitri John Ledkov wrote a message on the Ubuntu [Mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2016-June/016661.html) calling for the end of i386 support by Ubuntu 18.10. Ledkov argues that more software is being developed with 64-bit support. He is also concerned that it will be difficult to provide security support for the aging i386 architecture.

Comment: I read an article a while back from some Ubuntu or Debian devs, I can't remember which, that said they were literally having trouble getting hold of actual 32 bit only hardware to develop on. Computers today can run 32 bit software, but it's mainly as a backwards compatibility feature because they're 64 bit systems, and may behave differently than legit, 32 bit only systems.

Comment: Canonical has announced continued 32-bit support for 19.10 and 20.04 LTS https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts

Comment: That does not mean there will be a 32-bit OS @gapple (what was asked here). It means that when you install a 64-bit INSIDE that version you can use the 32-bit tools to install 32-bit software. Mind that this is likely only to apply to limited software: everybody else will be using the 64-bit version.