# Problem with installing 16.04. Tried upgrading from 14.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, 16.04

I am using 14.04 for a long time. Now today morning I tried upgrading to 16.04. All the packages were downloaded and installed. But after a few moments ( when I didn't pay attention to my laptop) it suddenly became a black screen. I tried `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, but that didn't work. So I forced shutdown. Now I start to boot my computer, its stuck in black screen. I tried reinstalling 16.04 from a pen drive but that shows

[image]

I tried booting up in recovery mode Ubuntu.It does show "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS..." on top. Hence the upgrade did something. But I am stuck in tty1. I dont know how to solve it on my own.

Any help is appreciated. Thanking in advance.

Comment: Live booting from Pendrive doesn't work?

Comment: Nope. Stuck with this.

Comment: That's strange, because Live booting should work regardless of broken installation on harddisk, *except* your bootable pendrive isn't properly bootable or the ISO you're using is broken. How did you download the ISO? Via torrent or HTTP?

Comment: Does your local ISO file checksum match what is on the Ubuntu official website?

Comment: Torrent. Live booting is when I try Ubuntu without installing, right?

Comment: Yes, and through that trying, you can install ubuntu through there.

Comment: What is checksum matching?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39389/discussion-between-rexford-and-shoham-debnath).

Comment: @Rexford you there? I did a check, and it seems fine

Comment: Help me understand more. How were you upgrading, via terminal or GUI? You say packages were Dow loaded and installed, if so, then upgrade was successful. After packages were installed, did you see any prompts?

Comment: I was away from the computer for a few minutes, and when I came back it was totally black. Nothing was responding, not even Ctrl+Alt+F1. So I forced shutdown. Then when I booted it up, it is completely blackscreen. Sometimes the tty1 window opens, but most of the times nothing happens.