# upgrade from14.04 to 15.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

I'm having a problem with upgrading from 14.04 to 15.05.The system collects all the files but during installation, approximately two thirds of the way through installation, the screen closes and there is no action on the harddrive. the system just sits and does nothing. Is this normal and I should just wait for it resolve it's self, or is there a problem that I'm unaware of?  The end result is that I'm unable to complete the upgrade. Please keep the answer as non technical as possible as I'm a 73 year old fuddy duddy  whose computer knowledge is somewhat limited, oh but learning.

Comment: 15.04 has reached end of life, and is no longer supported. I don't think it is a good idea to upgrade.

Comment: You should directly upgrade to 16.04. (please note that 14.04 and 16.04 are both LTS versions and you can skip the versions in between) Just check that "lts-versions only" is set in synaptic packaging tool. This might help:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)