# How to use systemd instead upstart?

Tags: 16.04, systemd, upstart

Suddenly `systemctl` stopped to work while I ssh'ed in my remote server to check service status. Output was

> Failed to list units: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

I discovered that now `upstart` is used (after a couple of reboots trying to make `systemctl` work).

Can I use `systemd` as my main init again? I didn't found any info how to switch from `upstart` to `systemd` [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers).

Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Comment: Thought of upgrading to 18.04?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson hmm, have'nt until now. Can I upgrade without breaking my webservers and so on? I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779544/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-without-losing-data) so far

Comment: Of course the process is backup and then upgrade!

Comment: Don't know what version of Ubuntu your using but did you see this on that link you provided? `First, it is important to note that systemd is only fully supported in Ubuntu 15.04 and later releases. While systemd is available in prior releases through the Ubuntu repositories, there is a deemphasis of support for these releases as noted here. Hence, it is advised to use the default upstart on prior releases.`

Comment: @Tarasovych: Nobody can guarantee that you won't need to tweak a thing or two to adapt to updated software. The upside is that you get an Ubuntu version which lasts until 2023 instead of 2021, and systemd is there by default.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen "Don't know what version of Ubuntu your using" - last line of my question :)

Comment: Sorry, bad eye sight!

Comment: See this https://serverfault.com/a/778202/369307, but of course a backup is need!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to George Udosen, I found this [article](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd).

I edited `/etc/default/grub` - added `init=/bin/systemd` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, than restarted the server `sudo shutdown -r now`