# Dell XPS 13 DE won't restart after failed update to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, upgrade, 16.04, restart

I tried updating my Dell XPS13 DE (9343) to Ubuntu 16.04 by using the below commands :

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Basically followed this blog post : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts

It errored out in between and now my machine would neither restart nor shutdown. Tried updating /etc/default/grub without any help. Please help!

Sorry I could not copy the error during upgrade, but for the below command now I get the error:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

```
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package hdapsd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-orca:
 gnome-orca depends on speech-dispatcher (>= 0.8); however:
  Package speech-dispatcher is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-orca (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-standard:
 ubuntu-standard depends on cron; however:
  Package cron is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-standard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of keyboard-configuration:
 keyboard-configuration depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-bin:
 grub-efi-amd64-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64:
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub-efi-amd64-bin (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tlp-rdw:
 tlp-rdw depends on tlp; however:
  Package tlp is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tlp-rdw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libmaven3-core-java (3.3.9-3) ...
Setting up maven (3.3.9-3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/maven/m2.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/maven/settings.xml ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-bin; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-bin is not configured yet.
 shim-signed depends on grub2-common (>= 2.00); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on keyboard-configuration; however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-radeon:
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-radeon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of procps:
 procps depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg:
 xserver-xorg depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.2-2); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-vesa:
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-vesa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamtk:
 clamtk depends on cron | cron-daemon; however:
  Package cron is not configured yet.
  Package cron-daemon is not installed.
  Package cron which provides cron-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package clamtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on udev (>= 154); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-cirrus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-tdfx:
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-tdfx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart:
 upstart depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-wacom:
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-input-abi-22 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-wacom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-input-abi-22 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-greeter:
 unity-greeter depends on upstart; however:
  Package upstart is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-greeter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:
 bluez depends on udev (>= 170-1); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-mach64:
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64 depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64 depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-mach64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
 indicator-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 indicator-bluetooth depends on gnome-bluetooth | ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-checkbox-support:
 python3-checkbox-support depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-checkbox-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xorg:
 xorg depends on xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+13ubuntu3); however:
  Package xserver-xorg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xorg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-checkbox-ng:
 python3-checkbox-ng depends on python3-checkbox-support (>= 0.22); however:
  Package python3-checkbox-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-checkbox-ng (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-ati:
 xserver-xorg-video-ati depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-ati depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-ati depends on xserver-xorg-video-radeon; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-radeon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-ati (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio:
 pulseaudio depends on udev (>= 143); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plainbox-provider-checkbox:
 plainbox-provider-checkbox depends on python3-checkbox-support (>= 0.22); however:
  Package python3-checkbox-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plainbox-provider-checkbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-sisusb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-intel:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-intel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center:
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-bluetooth; however:
  Package indicator-bluetooth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 binfmt-support
 speech-dispatcher
 whoopsie
 grub-common
 initscripts
 kerneloops-daemon
 irqbalance
 cron
 sane-utils
 tlp
 hdapsd
 gnome-orca
 ubuntu-standard
 keyboard-configuration
 grub-efi-amd64-bin
 grub-efi-amd64
 tlp-rdw
 grub2-common
 shim-signed
 xserver-xorg-core
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
 procps
 xserver-xorg
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa
 clamtk
 udev
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
 gnome-bluetooth
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
 upstart
 ubuntu-minimal
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom
 console-setup-linux
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
 unity-greeter
 bluez
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64
 indicator-bluetooth
 python3-checkbox-support
 xorg
 python3-checkbox-ng
 xserver-xorg-video-ati
 pulseaudio
 plainbox-provider-checkbox
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
 console-setup
 xserver-xorg-video-intel
 mountall
 unity-control-center
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

*Update*

The screen got locked after sometime, and each time I enter password it was coming back to the same enter password page. So I did a hard restart ( by long pressing power button)

Now once I start the laptop is stuck in splash screen and the caps lock is blinking constantly.

Please note that I do not care about the data. I want to bring the laptop back to working condition.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your post to include the error messages you saw during the upgrade.

Comment: The error is too big. Added some to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the data on your computer, and just want a working system, I would advise you to forget about fixing the upgrade and instead, just perform a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 using a bootable Ubuntu DVD or USB.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop has download links and links to how to make a bootable DVD or USB stick from various operating systems

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop shows how to install Ubuntu once you boot from a DVD or USB stick

Comment: Restored factory setting and it works fine now. Just wondering should I wait for 16.04.1 or should I try to upgrade again.