# Upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and now when I try to boot Windows from GRUB all I get is a purple screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

The GRUB options show:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Windows Boot Manager(on `/dev/sda1`)
System Setup
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

It has been partitioned and all my data exists.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't boot after upgrading to 16.04 (from 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804753/i-cant-boot-after-upgrading-to-16-04-from-14-04)

Comment: Looks like UEFI system. Grub only boots working Windows, so from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12 (check manual) as system starts from cold boot, can you directly boot Windows? If not then it is just a Windows issue. perhaps f8 when booting or use a Windows repair flash drive. Make sure Windows fast start up or hibernation is off and that NTFS does not need chkdsk as both prevent grub from booting Windows.

Comment: You ask "what is the problem?" That's my question of you. What is not working? Does something not boot from GRUB? Do you not understand what the various GRUB options do? Do you want to remove options from the GRUB menu? Do you want to see options in the GRUB menu that aren't there? Do you think GRUB is ugly and want to replace it with something else? Does GRUB make your dog bark annoyingly? You need to tell us what the problem is before we can help.

Comment: @RodSmith Windows does not load anymore I can only load ubuntu

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.