# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 failed at startup

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, 16.04

After upgrading to 16.04 by using the automatic upgrade, the system hangs at startup by prompting " [OK] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes." and never comes again.

I have no idea what to do ?
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and put following code.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

*and make sure your update system have no problem.*

then enter:

```
 sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks Asil, but how to open a terminal window when the startup doesn't finished and hangs ? Any key combinaison or somewhat way to get it ?

Comment: got the answer ctrl-alt-f2

Comment: I executed the update. At the end I got an error status ;
Errors were encountered while processing : kerneloops-daemon

Searching a way to solve this before continuing ... Any help is welcome also !

Comment: @MichelWicky great job.
You can search to solve the update error. just copy your code or catch the important keywords then search using it on askubuntu.com or google.

Comment: Everything went well after reinstalling kerneloops-daemon that was not installed. Thks.