# Upgrading 14.04 to 16.04 can't update UTMP at boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I used do-release-upgrade to switch from 14.04 to 16.04. After the upgrade cycle I rebooted and the boot gets stuck at upgrading the UTMP

This is a similar problem to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806068/upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-failed-at-startup), however when I accessed the command line I am unable to use apt-get as well, I get this error:

```
Relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0 symbol_znk.... Version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

So I'm guessing aptitude was lost in the failed upgrade...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: I can also see some failed steps before it got stuck:

```
Failed to start detect the available GPUs and deal with system changes...
Failed to start light display manager... 
Failed to start network manager wait online...
```

**UPDATE:** The user cowedly gave up on recovery and just reinstalled 16.04. Better luck for the next one.

Comment: you can try dpkg-reconfigure apt. See if that gets it working

Comment: @ravery didn't work, currently trying to figure out how to install apt directly with dpkg not sure what to put in **dpkg -i ::apt.deb??::**

Comment: it can't find the graphics card. but I am unsure if it is a kernel error or package error. do you need special drivers for your card?

Comment: dpkg -i apt. if the package is still cached it should work, your network is not initializing also so no internet. do you have a live cd?

Comment: @ravery I have a 14.04 life flash drive around, could I use one to fix the other?. **-i apt** was the 1st thing I tried (thought maybe I needed a full address or something). as for the gpu, its a laptop with both a an intel gpu and a nvidia's... the nvidia's needs proprietary drivers but the intel should work without extra stuff

Comment: I can also just make a life 16.04 a format the partition but thats what I was trying to avoid with the upgrade

Comment: yes thhe nvidia will need tweeking, but the intel should work f the back. the 14.04 flashdrive can be used to fix the other. boot from the flash drive and mount the broken one to a folder in your home directory, then chroot to the folder.

Comment: installing from scratch s an option, and may be faster than trying to fix the broken upgrade. use the live cd/flashdrive to back up personal data.

Comment: I have quite a few "academically developed"  software... reinstalling that would not be fast in any way I'm afraid

Comment: then I suggest to mount the broken install, chroot to it, and try to repair.

Comment: Well... I managed to mount into chroot but wasn't able to do anything significant towards recovery... Ended up giving up and just installing from scratch, thanks for the help and attention anyway @ravery