# Update 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS bricked

Tags: 16.04, updates

I have a Dell Optiplex 9020 which was running Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  Ubuntu complained that it was out of date and no longer providing security updates.  Of course, it did not offer a way to upgrade, but looking it up on stackexchange, I found the following advice:

[Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)

sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade

Now the machine locks up after booting.  I can't see anything in a log.
There is a text cursor.  Alt-F* does not work to get to a shell.

I can press the power button, and it then shows the ubuntu logo before shutting down in a controlled manner.  So Linux is running.

Any ideas as to how to recover my system?  I am assuming I should type some options in grub.

Booting with Linux 3.16.0-77-generic (recovery mode)

Recovery mode shows:

```
Started user manage for UID 112
started automatic USB/bluetooth printer setup...
Failed to start Network manager wait online
```

At this point ctrl-alt-del does not work, but pressing the power button does continue through the sequence and shut down.

Comment: Have you tried booting a LiveCD and exploring the logs on the Internal Disk, and/or backing up data?

Comment: Can you log in via recovery mode? If so do it and try sudo start lightdm. Might give some clues

Comment: 14.04 is still supported, so I am not sure what you saw about it being out of date.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

Comment: I just tried recovery mode.  It tries to start LWM, then something fails in the network.  But the screen gets wiped out and it goes by too fast.

Comment: 14.04LTS update said "this product is no longer updated. Security patches are no longer being distributed."

Comment: 14.04 is supported until [April 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) - it would be interesting to know what was causing the message that you saw.  Have you tried booting with nomodeset?

Comment: the screen goes blank until I press power or ctrl-alt-del, then it's too late.  How can I capture the log so I can paste it here?