# How To Upgrade Ubuntu installed on virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on Virtualbox and I wannted to upgrade it to the latest version (16.04 LTS).

I Upgrade it using my software updater, I restart my system. But, after restarting the system I found myself with the same old version (14.04). What's wrong guys?

Any suggestions?

/* Why my question is different to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release).

My question is totally different to the question identified as a possible duplicate. Because I was able to complete the update till the end and the OS asked me to restart the PC to finish the installation.

*/

Comment: No, it's not the same problem. I have Ubuntu running on a virtual machine (maybe this is the problem)

Comment: Can you expand your question to explain how this question is different from the one I provided the link for? I'm no stranger to running VM's and I can't fathom how this is any different. I understand that you think it's different. Perhaps if you were to [edit] your question to provide further detail (any errors you received during the upgrade process, etc.)  If your question is closed as a duplicate you are welcome to refer to http://askubuntu.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: Was the virtual machine writeable when you upgraded Ubuntu or did you use an earlier snapshot when you rebooted it?

Comment: It was writable. I resolved the problem by using the upgrade command. Thanks. (but I think there is a problem with software updater in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)