# how to get the latest version of gzip?

Tags: compression, gzip

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
I'm having `gzip` of version 1.4.

how do I get the latest version of it (say gzip 1.6)?

how to I upgrade to latest version of it?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS reached its End of Life and is not supported anymore. See this post: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16823/eol-notice-precise-pangolin-12-04-reached-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is End-Of-life and is not supported anymore.

You should upgrade to 16.04 (unless your system is running legacy code which can't run on 12.04)

Once you'll upgrade your Ubuntu to 16.04, you'll get newest version of gzip

Version 1.6 is the current version on 16.04

```
$ gzip --version
gzip 1.6
Copyright (C) 2007, 2010, 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1993 Jean-loup Gailly.
```

[How to upgrade to to 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)