# Ubuntu & Ryzen 3000 CPU

Tags: kernel, bios, usb-installation, amd-ryzen

I freshly built a new PC and want to dual boot it with an Ubuntu. Im having trouble to install it from my live usb stick, however.
The pc reaches Grub just fine but if I hit try Ubuntu or install it, the system can't start any module : they all fail to load.

After quick research, I've seen that this is a matter of Ryzen 3000 CPUs compatibility with the linux kernel that ships with Ubuntu.
Has anyone sucessfully installed ubuntu 19.04 on a Ryzen 3000 cpu / x570 shipset ?
My BIOS was updated at the time of building the pc, meaning the 20th of august. (MSI X570 Gaming edge Wifi)

Comment: See [Phoronix Article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-3700x-3900x-linux&num=2): Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is OK, but "On newer Linux distributions, there's a hard regression ... leaving newer Linux distributions unbootable. ... On all newer Linux distributions ... each time early in the boot process ... I've confirmed with AMD they do have an open issue surrounding "5.0.9" (the stock kernel of Ubuntu 19.04) ...". --- https://www.guru3d.com/news-story/new-firmware-update-reportedly-solves-ryzen-3000-boot-issues-linux.html --- Use older Ubuntu or newer Kernel with 19.04.

Comment: @Rob I thought about a newer kernel, but I have no idea how I could make a live stick with an other kernel version than the one provided with the ISO file... Maybe install it as 18.04, install the latest kernel and then run the update to 19.04 ?

Comment: Micheal [owns a ***lot*** of computers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Nl3.jpg), if he's been having trouble fixing it won't be easy. What you wrote in your comment is what I would try. Remember that you are allowed to answer your own question and choose your own answer as correct. There probably is an 'Upgrade your Kernel Boot-Stick' available that lets you boot and run off the USB, download and build, then install on the HD/SSD (leaving it bootable, without the stick) available (with some searching).

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/956885/914627) and some of the answers in the dupe explain how to upgrade just the kernel, boot Grub into recovery mode, along with some other things to check. Busy for a few hours, or I'd be more helpful.

Comment: Thats what i tried too but couldn't figure out how to get inrecovery. Holding shift didnt do it and couldn't open a command prompt. Thats fine you allready provided the needed info to find a solution, i'll try it tomorrow and will answer the topic appropriately

Comment: @Rob The 18.04 intermediate solution worked after some changes with the nvidia driver needed to be done, thank you so much !

Comment: We are glad to have been of help. If a better solution doesn't come up in a week it's entirely fair to choose your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huge thanks to [Rob](https://askubuntu.com/users/914627/rob) for providing the right [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174198/ubuntu-ryzen-3000-cpu#comment1959657_1174198). For better readability, I will sum it up here.

So the problem appears to be a compatibility issue of Ryzen 3000 CPUs with the kernel supplied in 19.04's ISO, causing all services to fail to load when either trying to live test it or install it.
This regression from previous kernels (including 18.04 LTS's one) can be worked around that way :

- Create an 18.04 live usb stick
- Once it is installed the way you want it to be, install [Ukuu](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) (kernel manager/installer) and upgrade to the latest kernel available. In my case, it is 5.2.14
- When its done, upgrade your distro as you usually do, in my case with a `sudo do-release-upgrade`
- enjoy your ubuntu 19.04 running on all those Ryzen cores !

If you find you are not having any display on your screen after logging in, you may want to install fresh Nvidia drivers (I used [this tutorial](https://www.mvps.net/docs/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-linux/)) replacing 390 by whichever version is downloadable when you do it, for me it was 418.
New drivers also fixed Xorg using 100% of the CPU's 12 threads when hovering the mouse around.

Comment: Good job. According to the [thread on Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/processors-memory/1111751-amd-ryzen-7-3700x-ryzen-9-3900x-offer-incredible-linux-performance-but-with-a-big-caveat/page7) (page 7&9) people still haven't got 19.04 to boot on Ryzen 3000. You might want to sign on anonymously and post the title of this question (I don't think new users can post links) there, or use your own account (there) if you don't care about linking your activity from various places together.

Comment: I will do something about it, if I can help :p

Comment: Patrick at STH had the same problem with an earlier OS and Ryzen chip. He [made up a script](https://www.servethehome.com/amd-ryzen-with-ubuntu-here-is-what-you-have-to-do-to-fix-constant-crashes/) which could be updated to work with a newer OS (and thus a newer Ryzen CPU). Thought I'd add the link in a comment in case someone else reading this wants to try that solution after updating the script.

Comment: Having upgraded my motherboard and CPU to a Ryzen 7 3800X, I was unable to boot. This was with 18.04 installed. I tried creating USB launchers of 20.04, 18.04.4, 18.04 and 16.04. While the details changed, none booted correctly. All failing during the process. The computer is fine, as it launches and runs Windows 10 reliably.