# Ubuntu 18.04 fails after boot on Ryzen 7 3700x

Tags: dual-boot, crash

I'm new to Ubuntu, i've managed to install it last month on my Dell Inspiron 7559 laptop and it work perfectly, so I wanted to install it on my desktop computer as well. But it just don't work.

I tried different USBs, different Ubuntu versions (19.10/18.04/Pop_os!/Fedora), but always the same thing happen, if I don't enable `nomodeset` and `acpi=off`, the installer will randomly crash before the installation end, but if I turn on `nomodeset` and `acpi=off`, I can install Ubuntu 18.04, but now when I'm on Ubuntu it always crash like 2-5min after I logged in. If I turn `nomodeset` and `acpi=off` it takes more time to crash, but it still crashes.

I tried to install AMD drivers, but it tells me that I don't have the correct kernel version even if I have the correct one, so Ubuntu on my desktop computer is just unusable.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
- Mobo: Gigabyte Aorus elite B450m
- Cooler master liquid ml120l RGB
- RAM: Corsair 16GB 2400mhz
- GPU: Gigabyte Radeon RX Vega 64 8GB
- SSD: PNY 1Tb nvme (Windows is installed on this drive)
- HDD: Western digital 2TB
- SSD: SanDisk 480 GB (Ubuntu is installed on this disk)
- PSU: Gigabyte GA 750H 750w

Comment: The problem you've stumbled upon is [well known](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-3700x-3900x-linux&num=2), and hopefully AMD will release a fix sooner rather then later. I don't think there is anything we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the hard regression [described here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-3700x-3900x-linux&num=2) and [here](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/processors-memory/1111751-amd-ryzen-7-3700x-ryzen-9-3900x-offer-incredible-linux-performance-but-with-a-big-caveat), download Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and install it. There's also a solution to test at [Ubuntu & Ryzen 3000 CPU](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1174198/ubuntu-ryzen-3000-cpu)