# Boot failure Ubuntu Ryzen 7 3800X CPU

Tags: boot, amd-processor, msi

I have a new install of Ryzen 7 3800X CPU on a MSI B450M Mortar Max motherboard.

I have tried the solutions mentioned at [Ubuntu & Ryzen 3000 CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174198/ubuntu-ryzen-3000-cpu) and elsewhere, however using vanilla installs of Ubuntu on a thumb drive does not work. I have tried USB launchers of 20.04, 18.04.4, 18.04 and 16.04. There is some variation in the outcome, but essentially the boot process fails in the early stages.

The computer hardware is working as I am able to boot and run Windows 10 on it.

AMD tech support said that Windows is supported and that the problem is with Linux support. "I suspect that issue might be with the Ubuntu OS driver and I suggest you please get in touch with OS distributor for the further assistance." Which really told me no more than I'd already guessed. Not really very helpful!

So, can anyone suggest any paths forward?

Thanks,
Nigel.

Comment: I tried today's testing build of 20.10. Still no success.

Comment: Ensure your B450 firmware is the latest.  Some early versions caused problems.

Comment: What Bios release does your board have?

Comment: It originally had a 260 release, dated 30 Dec 2019. I have updated that to the 280 release, dated 10 June 2020 and that did not solve the problem. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling IOMMU in the bios allowed Ubuntu to boot. (It was previously set to auto.)