ubuntu upgrade from one LTS to next consecutive LTS
I have 22.04 LTS and i want to upgrade to 24.04. In between there are intermediate release - 23 non-lts release. I read that you have to upgrade first to intermediate and then upgrade to next release. However, there is no clear statement I came across that this does not apply to LTS releases that we can upgrade one LTS to next LTS bypassing intermediate non-LTS releases. Can we do this for LTS? Can we upgrade 22.04 to 24.04 skipping 23 non-LTS release?

Wait until August.  Upgrader isn't released yet.

But also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release

If you read the release notes for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, it rather clearly says 22.04.1 being released on 15 August 2024 & that the upgrade from 22.04 LTS won't occur before this... If you check your calendar you'll note we're not yet at 15 August 2024.   https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-release-notes/39890   "Users of 22.04 LTS however will be offered the automatic upgrade when 24.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 15th of August."

confusion is 24.04 is already available for iso image on https://ubuntu.com/desktop and which is LTS. What is special about 15th august that only upgrades are kept on hold? Apart from this I do not see 24.04 LTS has disk encryption for partitions when installation through iso is used.
